# Tiny hole/seams between jigsaw models created from svg in Unity?

Tags: modeling, faces, .fbx

I have some models of jigsaw puzzle pieces made from a svg that I'm trying to use in Unity. Everything looks fine perfectly aligned with no gaps/seams in Blender, but when I try to use them in Unity I get the tiny gaps/seams inbetween the puzzle pieces that especially visible if panning/zooming the camera around.

The process I used for the models was

- Import svg into Blender
- Select all and Convert to Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text
- Select each pieces Face then (F) Fill
- UV map all pieces to image from bounds

in Blender the puzzle pieces look this after

[image]

[image]

[image]

but after importing into Unity I notice there all these tiny seams/gaps between all the pieces that appear/disappear as you are panning/zooming camera around.(Texture changed for visibility of seams/gaps)

[image]

I have also tried triangulating the Faces after filling each piece and I still get the same gaps/seams between models. Everything looks fine in both the Blender and the original svg file with no gaps and seams, any advice would be appreciated, thanks.